# changing the HAVING changes the column values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a query that, when ran, has, as the values in the last column, 1, 4 and 8. But when I change the HAVING condition those values become 1, 3 and 5. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT memberId, @temp:=total AS total, @runningTotal as runningTotal, @runningTotal:=@temp+@runningTotal AS newRunningTotal
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS memberId, 1 AS total UNION
    SELECT 2, 2 UNION
    SELECT 3, 2
) AS temp
JOIN (SELECT @temp:=0) AS temp2
JOIN (SELECT @runningTotal:=0) AS temp3
HAVING newRunningTotal <= 40;
```

Here's the SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27761/0

If I change newRunningTotal to runningTotal I get different numbers in the runningTotal and newRunningTotal. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Here's the SQL fiddle for the changed query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27762/0

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) is quite explicit against doing what you are doing in the `select`:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:

```
SET @a = @a + 1;
```

> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:

```
SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
```

> However, the order of evaluation for
>   expressions involving user variables is undefined.

I think you have found a situation where it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

use this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27767/0) to specify less than 40,
or this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27769/0) also to specify less than 40.

I think what's happening is HAVING is applied after everything is done, but because you have variables in your select, they get calculated again giving you no control.